# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

radio button for answering quiz and my radio button is

```
<input id="ans_ans1" name="ans" type="radio" value="ans1">
```

my next ajax request is

```
<a href="#" onclick="Element.show('loader'); jQuery.ajax({data:'answer='+$('ans').value+'&amp;passed_question=1&amp;'+'&amp;exam_group_id=1&amp;' + '&amp;authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('GGKdjhC39b1Fi5fe52Cq0VcPwpi6laphZblC/5ZOl8o='), dataType:'script', success:function(request){Element.hide('loader')}, type:'post', url:'/answers/next'}); return false;">Next</a>
```

in my console

> $('ans').value gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

any one help me to get the value of radio button in ajax request

Comment: Because there is no element with tag name as 'ans'. It should have been `$('#ans_ans1').val()`.

Comment: Are you **sure** you're using jQuery and not Prototype or MooTools? *"$('ans').value gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"* That makes no sense with jQuery. jQuery's `$` function always returns non-`null`. It may return an *empty* set, but it will return non-`null`. Whereas the `$` from either Prototype or MooTools will return `null` if there's no element with the matching `id` (and there isn't, in your example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears you're using [PrototypeJS](http://prototypejs.org/) along with jQuery -- [`Element.show()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/show/):

Prototype's [`$()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/) expects its argument to be the value of an `id` rather a `name`. So

```
$('ans').value
```

should be

```
$('ans_ans1').value
```

To match the `<input`**`id="ans_ans1"`**`...>` in the markup.

---

If you'd like to select by `name` instead, you can use [`$$()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) with an attribute selector. Though, it'll return a collection.

```
$$('[name="ans"]')[0].value
```

Comment: i have multiple radio button <input id="ans_ans1" name="ans" type="radio" value="ans1"> <input id="ans_ans2" name="ans" type="radio" value="ans2"> <input id="ans_ans3" name="ans" type="radio" value="ans3"> <input id="ans_ans4" name="ans" type="radio" value="ans4">

Comment: Assuming that means you want the value of the one the user clicked, Prototype's `$$()` supports the same `:checked` pseudo-class [as jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) -- `$$('[name="ans"]:checked')[0].value`.

Comment: Yes it works but one prob when i give "ans"  it gives error                     syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
...h => "'answer='+$$('[name="ans"]:checked')[0].value;+'&passe...

Comment: @RajaSekar Ah. That's probably because it's inside an `onclick=""` attribute which is already using `"` quotes. So, you'll need to escape/encode those in the selector -- `$$('[name=&quot;ans&quot;]:checked')[0].value`.

Comment: sorry it doesnt work..... when i use that in console                    $$('[name=&quot;ans&quot;]:checked')[0].value
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Tahnk u so much it works but i give $$('[name*=ans]:checked')[0].value

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you're using a *mix* of jQuery and either Prototype or MooTools. *(See below for why.)*

If so, my first recommendation is stop doing that. Pick one and use it throughout.

But your main problem is that you're looking up an element using an `id` (`"ans"`) that doesn't exist. The `id` is `ans_ans1`. So either:

```
$("ans_ans1").value         // Prototype / MooTools using raw `value` prop
```

or

```
$("ans_ans1").getValue()    // Prototype
$("ans_ans1").get('value'); // MooTools
```

or

```
jQuery("#ans_ans1").val()   // jQuery
```

---

Why I think you're using a mix of libraries:

1. You've said:

   > $('ans').value gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

   That makes no sense with jQuery. jQuery's `$` function always returns non-`null`. It may return an *empty* set, but it will return non-`null`. Whereas the `$` from either Prototype or MooTools will return `null` if there's no element with the matching `id` (and there isn't, in your example).
2. When calling jQuery's `ajax`, you're using the symbol `jQuery`, not `$`, which suggests to me you're using jQuery's `noConflict` so that you can have Prototype or MooTools co-exist with it (because those want `$`).

Comment: i have multiple radio button                                               <input id="ans_ans1" name="ans" type="radio" value="ans1">              <input id="ans_ans2" name="ans" type="radio" value="ans2">                  <input id="ans_ans3" name="ans" type="radio" value="ans3">                    <input id="ans_ans4" name="ans" type="radio" value="ans4">

Comment: when i using $("ans_ans1").value it returns ans1.. for all radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
<a href="#" onclick="Element.show('loader'); jQuery.ajax({data:'answer='+$('#ans_ans1').value+'&amp;passed_question=1&amp;'+'&amp;exam_group_id=1&amp;' + '&amp;authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('GGKdjhC39b1Fi5fe52Cq0VcPwpi6laphZblC/5ZOl8o='), dataType:'script', success:function(request){Element.hide('loader')}, type:'post', url:'/answers/next'}); return false;">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
$('ans').value
```

This

```
$('#ans_ans1').val()
```

Comment: That would be reasonable if the OP really is using jQuery, but the error message the OP has quoted suggests the he/she isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The selector is wrong and the method to retrive value :

Modified:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Element.show('loader'); jQuery.ajax({data:'answer='+$('#ans_ans1').val()+'&amp;passed_question=1&amp;'+'&amp;exam_group_id=1&amp;' + '&amp;authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('GGKdjhC39b1Fi5fe52Cq0VcPwpi6laphZblC/5ZOl8o='), dataType:'script', success:function(request){Element.hide('loader')}, type:'post', url:'/answers/next'}); return false;">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer this [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

You can change

```
$('ans').value
```

into

```
$("input[value='ans1']" ).val()
```

or

```
$('#ans_ans1').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
$('#ans_ans1')
```

or

```
$("input[id='ans_ans1']")
```

or

```
$("input[name='ans']")
```

to get the value just 
Use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) 
like this `$('#ans_ans1').val();`

I guess you should study some content on [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)